# Wrap a double** c++ function with cython

Tags: python, c++, pointers

I have a C++ function which returns a pointer `double**` - a high dimensional  matrix in particular - and I'd like to wrap it to some python code using Cython. How should I act?

Here an example  with a function with a `double*` pointer for sake of simplicity.

My C++ `fib.cpp` code:

```
double add(double a, double b)
{
 return a+b;
}

double p[]= {1,2,3,4}; 

double* mult(double a)    
{
p[0]=p[0]*a;
p[1]=p[1]*a;
return p; 
}
```

Then there is the `fib.hpp` file:

```
double add(double a,double b);
double* mult(double a);
```

Then the pxd file `fib.pxd`:

```
cdef extern from "fib.hpp":
     double add(double a,double b);
     double* mult(double a);
```

In the end the pyx file

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = fib.cpp 

cimport fib 

def add(a,b):
    return fib.add(a,b)
def mult(a):           # dropping these lines
    return fib.mult(a) # the code works without the double* function
```

Everything  is compiled with the rather standard `setup.py` :

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext = Extension("fib2cpp",
            sources=["fib.pyx", "fib.cpp"],
            language="c++")

setup(name="fib",
ext_modules=cythonize(ext))
```

When I compile the code:

```
setup.py build_ext -if
```

> Cannot convert '`double *`' to python object.

When I try with a `double**` function I get the same error.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for the case `double *`. First of all, the  file `fib.pxd` is useless. 
Then we need a new `fib.pyx` file:

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = fib.cpp


import numpy as np 
cimport numpy as cnp 



cdef extern from "fib.hpp":
     double fib(int n)
     double add (double a, double b)
     double* mult(double a)



def make_mult(double a):
    cdef double[:] mv = <double[:4]> mult(a) # the 4 stands for
    return np.asarray(mv)   # the dimension of the array defined in fib.cpp
```

In the case of a function which returns a nrows*ncols matrix; such as `double* make_mat(int nrows, int ncols)` , the second line of the  function `make_mult` has to be rewritten as:

```
cdef double[:,:] mv=<double[:nrows,:ncols]> make_mat(nrows, ncols)
```

Regrettably, If I have a  function `double** make_mat(int nrows, int ncols)` which always returns a matrix, then the previous code rises the error :

> Pointer base type does not match cython.array base type